# Fallback for unresolvable constructor arguments in StructureMap

Tags: structuremap

Suppose I have a class

```
public class Foo()
{
    public Foo(Bar bar){}
    public Foo():this(Bar.Default){}
}
```

I want StructureMap to use the first constructor overload when `bar` can be resolved by the container, but the second when it cannot.

How can I configure the container to do this (both in general, and specifically for the `Foo` class?)

Comment: See [Dependency Injection anti-pattern: multiple constructors](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97)

Answer (score 1):

Foo has a dependency on Bar so you should model that as a single constructor, it is up to your container to inject the correct implementation of Bar.

So when you configure your container you should apply detection of when bar cannot  be resolved and the default should be used

```
        Container cont = new Container(c =>
        {
            if (useDefaultBar)
            {
                c.For<IBar>().Use<Bar>(Bar.Default);
            }
            else
            {
                c.For<IBar>().Use<Bar>();
            }
        });
```